# Flutter with firestore missing method

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#get on channel plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore)
```

Hello, i keep having this message for all the methods of firestore with flutter on an android device simulator. 
I followed the install instruction ("gms...google services" in first gradle  and plugin on app gradle file, + the google services.json on app folder.

It seems that i should add the firestore api on the android dependencies but this is not on the officiel installation guide.

my pubspec.yaml :

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.2.5
#  firebase_auth: ^0.5.20
  cloud_firestore: ^0.8.0
  rxdart: ^0.18.1
```

Comment: Big news, it seems it's actually working on main project but i'm having this error as i was running it in unit testing ... maybe a bug to report

Comment: You can try Firebase_core: any because latest version of Firebase core dependancy is not working properly.

Answer (score 2):

Plugins depend on the native platform. You need to mock it to make code depending on it run without a device/emulator.
See https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/MethodChannel/setMockMethodCallHandler.html, https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/BinaryMessages/setMockMessageHandler.html, https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/BasicMessageChannel-class.html