# Can anyone help me on this flutter error, i am learning flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

currently i am using flutter with firebase to add signin with facebook and google. Now when i add facebook login with help of all the documentation. I dont know what is wrong with the app. It is only showing the CircularprocessingIndicator while the app is running.
**error on terminal**

```
 Launching lib/main.dart on POCO F1 in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
                                                   
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       150.7s (!)
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...                         9.1s
W/FlutterActivity( 3108): Tried to automatically register plugins with FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@7fcef82) but could not find and invoke the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.
I/le.helloflutte( 3108): Background concurrent copying GC freed 88786(4991KB) AllocSpace objects, 52(1876KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3313KB/6627KB, paused 5.473ms total 97.924ms
W/Gralloc3( 3108): mapper 3.x is not supported                          
I/Choreographer( 3108): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Syncing files to device POCO F1...                                 663ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload. 
R Hot restart.
h Repeat this help message.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
An Observatory debugger and profiler on POCO F1 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:43387/ciERcuBRCco=/
E/flutter ( 3108): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method startListeningAuthState on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)
E/flutter ( 3108): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
E/flutter ( 3108): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3108): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
E/flutter ( 3108): #2      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.<anonymous closure> (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:308:25)
E/flutter ( 3108): #3      _runGuarded (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:820:24)
E/flutter ( 3108): #4      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:215:7)
E/flutter ( 3108): #5      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:833:19)
E/flutter ( 3108): #6      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:475:9)
E/flutter ( 3108): #7      new _ForwardingStreamSubscription (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:125:10)
E/flutter ( 3108): #8      _ForwardingStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:93:16)
E/flutter ( 3108): #9      _ForwardingStream.listen (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:88:12)
E/flutter ( 3108): #10     new _ForwardingStreamSubscription (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:125:10)
E/flutter ( 3108): #11     _ForwardingStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:93:16)
E/flutter ( 3108): #12     _ForwardingStream.listen (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:88:12)
E/flutter ( 3108): #13     _StreamBuilderBaseState._subscribe (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:137:37)
E/flutter ( 3108): #14     _StreamBuilderBaseState.initState (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:111:5)
E/flutter ( 3108): #15     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4640:58)
E/flutter ( 3108): #16     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter ( 3108): #17     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter ( 3108): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter ( 3108): #19     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter ( 3108): #20     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter ( 3108): #21     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
E/flutter ( 3108): #22     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter ( 3108): #23     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter ( 3108): #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter ( 3108): #25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5830:14)
E/flutter ( 3108): #26     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter ( 3108): #27     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter ( 3108): #28     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter ( 3108): #29     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter ( 3108): #30     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
E/flutter ( 3108): #31     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter ( 3108): #32     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter ( 3108): #33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter ( 3108): #34     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5830:14)
E/flutter ( 3108): #35     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter ( 3108): #36     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter ( 3108): #37     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5830:14)
E/flutter ( 3108): #38     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter ( 3108): #39     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter ( 3108): #40     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter ( 3108): #41     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
E/flutter ( 3108): #42     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter ( 3108): #43     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
E/flutter ( 3108): #44     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/
I/le.helloflutte( 3108): ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=2821 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
```

landing page where to check using stream builder.

```
import 'package:helloflutter/app/home_page.dart';
import 'package:helloflutter/app/service/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:helloflutter/app/sign_in/sign_in_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'service/firebase_auth.dart';

class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  LandingPage({@required this.auth});
  final AuthBase auth;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          User user = snapshot.data;
          if (user == null) {
            return SignInPage(
              auth: auth,
            );
          }
          return HomePage(
            auth: auth,
          );
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, choose a title that describes your issue, so it can catch the attention of other users who might be able to help

Comment: did you add  FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this) in your Application class, or  override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin");
    }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter with firestore missing method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467457/flutter-with-firestore-missing-method)

Comment: Have you added the `firebase_core` package?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the [firebase_auth package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth). Make sure this is in your pubspec: `firebase_auth: ^0.16.1` (Or whichever version you want to use) and then import it into your file like:

`import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';`

In your code there is only 'import service/firebase_auth.dart' which I'm guessing is a local file where you have defined some code.